# Can i have a install button for a chrome extension on my website?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i was wondering if it's possible for a user to install a Chrome extension through my website in any possible way instead via Google's marketplace.

Thanks!

Comment: It used to be possible to just link to the `.crx` file... I've heard that there are restrictions on this these days.  I haven't tried it in years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation from Google](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/2664769?hl=en), users can install your extension via your website. The recommended way is for you to [enable inline installation of your extension](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation); otherwise, users will need to do the following:

1. Download the extension file from the website and save it to your computer.
2. Click the Chrome menu icon Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
3. Select Tools > Extensions.
4. Locate the extension file on your computer and drag the file onto the Extensions page.
5. Review the list of permissions in the dialog that appears. If you would like to proceed, click Install.

Comment: As December 2018 Chrome no longer allows inline installation. They removed the feature and won't be replacing it. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/inline_faq